# Find the speed of stream from rowing speeds with and against the stream

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

#### Problem

A man rows to a place 48 km distant and come back in 14 hours. He finds that he can row 4 km with the stream in the same time as 3 km against the stream. The rate of the stream is:

> (A)  1 km/hr; (B):   1.5 km/hr; (C): 2 km/hr; (D):   2.5 km/hr

#### Progress

I don't know how to solve these. Anybody can help me with these. Book answer is 1km/hr

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far. For instance, what do you think a solution might look like? :)

Comment: @Shaun Check out here for boats and stream concept `http://mrunal.org/2012/04/aptitude-boats-and-streams-made-easy.html`

Comment: Since this is homework, we'd prefer it if you provide *your own* thoughts on the problem. This isn't some site where people do your homework *for you*; it's for improving one's mathematical abilities. We would rather help you even more by helping you to do your homework yourself! :)

Comment: @Shaun I got an answer with the help of satish.I am a new user to these site.next time I will share my own thought while posting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

V = speed of the boat
U = speed of the stream

$(V+U).t =4$

$(V-U)*t = 3$

$\frac{(V+U)}{(V-U)} = \frac{4}{3}$

Solving this you get $V = 7U$

$(V+U)*t_1 = 48$

$(V-U)*t_2 = 48$

$t_1 + t_2 = 14$

$8U*t_1 = 48$

$6U*t_2 = 48$

$\frac{48}{8U} + \frac{48}{6U} = 14$

Solving this we get U = 1

Thanks

Satish

Comment: Thank you for solving these to me.now I am get some clear idea about these.